# JavaScript error + Object doesn't support property or method 'pubads'

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var googletag = googletag || {};
googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
(function() {
var gads = document.createElement('script');
gads.async = true;
gads.type = 'application/javascript';
var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') + 
'//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
})();
```

Any advice would be great.

thx

Comment: Is `googletag.pubads()` available in the function that you're pushing onto `googletag.cmd`?

Comment: set a `console.log(googletag);` before the function call and check its ouput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you try use module before it's loading, and you even force such behavior with "async=true" so it seems to be copy-paste.

By your hands U can observe "load" event of your hand-made script tag and react on it.

But VERY STRONG SUGGESTION - not be lazy, download, learn and read STANDARD script for such tasks - REQUIRE.JS - http://requirejs.org/